# How to differentiate value of array with two object with same key in java

Tags: android, json, arraylist, google-sheets

I am implementing an Android app. I have a google spreadsheet with 100 rows and 2 columns. I am fetching record of google spreadsheet in my app. I got the JSON response like that :

`JSON Response`

```
{
     "version": "0.6",
      "reqId": "0",
      "status": "ok",
      "sig": "862971983",
      "table": {
        "cols": [
          {
            "id": "A",
            "label": "Name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "id": "B",
            "label": "PhoneNo",
            "type": "number",
            "pattern": "General"
          }
        ],
        "rows": [
          {
            "c": [
              {
                "v": "A Anil C Agrawal"
              },
              {
                "v": 7926605853,
                "f": "7926605853"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "c": [
              {
                "v": "A Balaji Agarwal"
              },
              {
                "v": 8463225752,
                "f": "8463225752"
              }
            ]
          },.................
```

Here I have **C** is array type with two object with same key but I want this same keys in different variable for Ex. String Name, String PhoneNo.

Here is my method which is fetching google spreadsheet response and print it. If I print the value of Name so its showing both Name and phone number but I want like that Name= Abc and PhoneNo = 8574968521.

```
public void getSpreadSheetData() {
        String result = getSpreadSheetResponce();
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (result == null) {
            Log.e("net not present:", "");
        } else {
            int start = result.indexOf("{", result.indexOf("{") + 1);
            int end = result.lastIndexOf("}");
            String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);

            try {
                JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                String Name = null;

                if (mainObj != null) {
                    JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("rows");
                    if (list != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject innerJsonObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (innerJsonObject != null) {
                                //
                                JSONArray valuesJsonArray = innerJsonObject
                                        .getJSONArray("c");
                                if (valuesJsonArray != null) {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < valuesJsonArray
                                            .length(); j++) {
                                        JSONObject innerElem = valuesJsonArray
                                                .getJSONObject(j);
                                        if (innerElem != null) {
                                            Name = innerElem.getString("v");
                                            arrayList.add(Name);
                                            Log.i("arrayList", "" + arrayList);

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private String getSpreadSheetResponce() {

        String responce = " ";
        String urlString = "";
        try {
            String FETCH_ROW_WITH_WHERE_CLAUSE_URL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tq&key=1n_VjwHm8qIU5YRMM-wMkJIap2KZa5vOfxWI5dpYT1PE&gid=1262286779";
            URL urlspreadsheet = new URL(FETCH_ROW_WITH_WHERE_CLAUSE_URL);
            URLConnection urlConnection = urlspreadsheet.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            if (urlConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter an HTTP URL.");
            }
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
            String current;

            while ((responce = in.readLine()) != null) {
                urlString += responce;
                System.out.println(urlString);
                Log.e("Response::", "in loop:" + urlString);
            }
            Log.e("Response::", "final response:" + urlString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return urlString;

    }
```

Is it to possible please help me.

Comment: are you sure about there will be two objects only in the c array? then you can check them with position of element in your loop and assign it wherever you want Otherwise I didn't understand it correctly

Comment: Yes, I am sure. You can see JSON respnse. it all clear about your query. @Dev

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to get this array by json object name. 
means you have to use here Object key.

```
//JSONObject c = Jsonobj.getJSONObject("row");
//convert your jsonarray in json object
Iterator<String> it = c.keys();// check for first and next object
while (it.hasNext()) { // call while we have next object in array
String Key = it.next(); // this will get next obj name in string "c"
JSONObject keyobj = new JSONObject(c.toString()); // this will gat "c" object array from json
```

1. get "rows" array in Json object
2. now do not get object "c" but use here object key method
3. check till "row" array has no any object
4. in you JSON this method will call two time and you will easily get this all data with same object name

Answer (score 0):

@ abc please use this method . It will solve your problem. If any problem then comment below.

```
private void json(String jsonString) {
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject mainObj = null;
try {
  mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
String Name = null;

if (mainObj != null) {
  try {
    JSONObject tableObject = mainObj.getJSONObject("table");
      JSONArray rowMasterArray = tableObject.getJSONArray("rows");          
      if (rowMasterArray != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowMasterArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject rowsObject= rowMasterArray.getJSONObject(i);
          if (rowsObject != null) {
              JSONArray rowsItemArray = rowsObject.getJSONArray("c");
              if (rowsItemArray != null) {
                for (int k = 0; k < rowsItemArray.length(); k++) {
                  JSONObject innerElem = rowsItemArray.getJSONObject(k);
                  if (innerElem != null) {
                    Name = innerElem.getString("v");
                    arrayList.add(Name);
                    Log.i("arrayList", "" + arrayList);
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
      }
  }catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks but where you print the value of Phone no?

Comment: @abc Hey I saw your post...I think you have figured out how to get phone number. Therefore I think my answer can also be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my question. I did some changes in my method that is getSpreadSheetData().
Here I did some logical mistake now it solved

```
public void getSpreadSheetData() {
        hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        String result = getSpreadSheetResponce();
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (result == null) {
            Log.e("net not present:", "");
        } else {
            int start = result.indexOf("{", result.indexOf("{") + 1);
            int end = result.lastIndexOf("}");
            String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);

            try {
                JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                String Name = null;

                if (mainObj != null) {
                    JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("rows");
                    if (list != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject innerJsonObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (innerJsonObject != null) {
                                //
                                JSONArray valuesJsonArray = innerJsonObject
                                        .getJSONArray("c");
                                if (valuesJsonArray != null) {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                                        JSONObject innerElem = valuesJsonArray
                                                .getJSONObject(j);
                                        if (innerElem != null) {
                                            Name = innerElem.getString("v");
                                            // arrayList.add(Name);
                                            Log.e("name no:",
                                                    "" + Name.toString());
                                            JSONObject SecondElement = valuesJsonArray
                                                    .getJSONObject(j + 1);
                                            if (SecondElement != null) {
                                                String phone = SecondElement
                                                        .getString("f");
                                                Log.e("Phone no:",
                                                        "" + phone.toString());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Log.e("Name Last", "" + Name);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```